# Are there any transparent photoconductors?

Tags: time, conductivity

Are there any transparent photoconductors? If so, can I know the timeframes of some examples of them where they reach full conductivity? I need one that reaches full(or approximately full) conductivity fast enough that it can be used for gigahertz frequencies.

Comment: PD's in GHz range are limited to shielded GaAs  parts for fibre-optic apps.  Do you have any experience in this area?

Comment: I'm willing to learn.

Comment: If something is truly transparent, then light doesn't interact with it.  Therefore something *can't* be photoresistive (what you mean by photoconductor?) to the extent it is transparent.

Comment: Perhaps something partially transparent, transparent enough for light to travel through it, yet still react to some of the photons? after all no material is completely transparent...

Comment: All exposed semiconductors are photon sensitive. But for speed reasons, you probably need GaAs.. go read. https://www.google.ca/search?q=pd+gaAs&client=firefox-b&dcr=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1w6-Mi-zXAhVhqlQKHXIcBLEQ_AUICigB&biw=1408&bih=689

Comment: the last sentence of your post makes no sense. ... light does not start out slow and then speed up. ... i think that statement is based on false information.

Comment: Photoconductors don't toggle, they ramp (it takes a dose of light to create charge carriers).  There's negligible turnon time delay except due to the illumination brightness and channel capacity.

Comment: Use a beam-splitter. You can set the percentage of pass/reflect and set any of the usual detector/conductors at the right angle position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe look at a doped CVD [diamond](http://cdn.intechweb.org/pdfs/17229.pdf) semiconductor (photodiode) with ITO contacts.